# Quarkus Extension JAX-RS Provider doesn't get injected with CDI Beans

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm building a quarkus extension that has a set of JAX-RS `ExceptionMapper` instances.  These instances need to be injected with my common error handler that I create with a producer class.

When I integration test it, the Error Handler isn't being injected into the Mappers but it is available to be injected elsewhere (aka my Test Resource class).

The interesting thing is that this does work properly if I have the mappers and the config class in a stand-alone Quarkus app.

here's the code in question:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ErrorMessageUtilProducer {
    @Inject ErrorMessageUtilConfig errorMessageUtilConfig;

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    public ErrorMessageUtil errorMessageUtil() {
        return new ErrorMessageUtil(
                errorMessageUtilConfig.orgCode,
                errorMessageUtilConfig.systemTag,
                new JacksonPropertiesLoader());
    }
}
```

And one of the mappers (with a base class):

```
public abstract class ExceptionMappingBase<T extends Throwable> implements ExceptionMapper<T> {
    @Inject ErrorMessageUtil errorMessageUtil;

    // dummy constructor required by CDI
    public ExceptionMappingBase() {}

    @Inject
    public ExceptionMappingBase(ErrorMessageUtil errorMessageUtil) {
        this.errorMessageUtil = errorMessageUtil;
    }

    /**
     * Private method to resolve the appropriate HTTP Status code.
     *
     * @param error
     * @param defaultStatus
     * @return
     */
    protected Response.Status resolveHttpStatusCode(Error error, Response.Status defaultStatus) {
        return Response.Status.fromStatusCode(
                NumberUtils.toInt(error.getStatus(), defaultStatus.getStatusCode()));
    }

    /**
     * Private method which converts the Error into a Response object and this method assumes that
     * the default error is a 500.
     *
     * @param error
     * @return
     */
    protected Response resolveResponse(Error error) {
        return resolveResponse(error, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * Private method which converts the Error into a Response object.
     *
     * @param error
     * @param defaultStatus
     * @return
     */
    protected Response resolveResponse(Error error, Response.Status defaultStatus) {
        return Response.status(resolveHttpStatusCode(error, defaultStatus))
                .entity(errorMessageUtil.createErrorsObject(error))
                .build();
    }
}

@Provider
public class BaseExceptionHandler extends ExceptionMappingBase<BaseException> {
    // dummy constructor required by CDI
    public BaseExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Inject
    public BaseExceptionHandler(ErrorMessageUtil errorMessageUtil) {
        super(errorMessageUtil);
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BaseException exception) {
        return resolveResponse(errorMessageUtil.createErrorMessage(exception));
    }
}
```

And the build item in the deployment module looks like:

```
class QuarkusErrorHandlingProcessor {

    private static final String FEATURE = "quarkus-error-handling";

    @BuildStep
    void feature(BuildProducer<FeatureBuildItem> feature) {
        feature.produce(new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE));
    }

    @BuildStep
    public AdditionalBeanBuildItem additionalBeanBuildItem() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder()
                .addBeanClass(ErrorMessageUtilProducer.class)
                .setDefaultScope(DotNames.SINGLETON)
                .setUnremovable()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to a previous self-answer it; it looks like you need to register the providers as a build step to ensure that they are tied together:

```
@BuildStep
    public AdditionalBeanBuildItem additionalBeanBuildItem() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder()
                .addBeanClasses(
                        ErrorMessageUtilProducer.class,
                        BaseExceptionHandler.class,
                        ThrowableHandler.class)
                .setDefaultScope(DotNames.SINGLETON)
                .setUnremovable()
                .build();
    }
```